# Aloha POS API. Aloha connect

Tags: api, point-of-sale

I have one question about API and where I can find something about it.

I develop POS System and my customer want's to integrate it with aloha POS System using aloha connect. In the Internet I found only info about what is it and how this API is good, but I can't find any place where I can find this API and maybe some Samples.

Already I wrote to Aloha support but they didn't answer me. So I deside to answer you here.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to get approval and purchase it from NCR, with a minimum of 100 monthly POS system integration licenses.  They do not allow unauthorized access, keys will be required.